# Why does not work translates in include template Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I include template `.blade` using the following code:

```
@include('common.no-results')
```

Inside I try to get word translation:

```
`<p>{{ trans('index.no_results_text') }}</p>`
```

Just it print only: `index.no_results_text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the specified language line does not exist, the trans function will simply return the language line key. So, using the example above, the trans function would return `index.no_results_text` if the language line does not exist.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization#retrieving-language-lines)

Comment: This line exists in translation file

Comment: @MisterPI What is the path to your translation file? Taking english as default it should be `resources\lang\en\index.php`